# java application using webservice

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, cxf

I am experimenting on how to use a web service in a java application. Here are the things I did:

- I created a web service from a class in a dynamic web project.( Using CXF )
- I used my eclipse to generate client classes for this web service from another dynamic web project.
- I copied all these automatically generated classes into my java project.
- I now have a class that calls all these classes. But I am getting an exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server
>   sent HTTP status code 404: Not Found at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown
>   Source) at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown
>   Source) at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown
>   Source) at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown
>   Source) at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown
>   Source) at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Unknown Source)
>   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) at $Proxy30.getUserInformation(Unknown Source) at
>   servicepackage.UserLogin$2.actionPerformed(UserLogin.java:91) at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source) at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

- What are the usual reasons for this exception ? Can someone help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This error `The server sent HTTP status code 404:` says it all.

Comment: I checked the uri, Its valid. both the service and client are in my local system. the server is also running.

Comment: Check to see if you can you view the wsdl of the web-service via browser.

Comment: Yes I can see the webservice over the browser. the server is running.

Comment: Can you add your client code over here?